# How to reduce Xamarin debug console messages

Tags: xamarin

I use `Debug.WriteLine` in Xamarin to view some responses to user interaction (for example), but Xamarin is writing several messages on it.

How can I reduce the number or avoid `Verbose` and not important messages that Xamarin send to the console?

Change to `Release` is not valid for me!

Comment: Can you go to `Options>Xamarin>Android Settings` and set the output verbosity to Quiet and see if that works for you!

Comment: It reduces the amount of lines, but still having. Thanks @FreakyAli

Comment: I think there is no other way to minimise it any further.